# Redux reducer state not updating

Tags: redux, return, react-redux, state, reducers

```js
import types from "../actions/types";
export default function(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.fetchCartProducts:
      return action.payload || false;
    case types.modifyCart:
      debugger;
      switch (action.payload.operation) {
        case "subtract":
          const index = action.payload.index;
          let isSingleCount = state[index] === 1;
          let chosenIds = state;
          if (isSingleCount) {
            chosenIds = chosenIds.filter(index => index != index);
          } else {
            [
              ...chosenIds.slice(0, index),
              { ...chosenIds[index], count: chosenIds[index].count - 1 },
              ...chosenIds.slice(index + 1)
            ];
          }
          return (
            chosenIds
          )
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```js
{
          "Products": [
            {
              index: 1,
              name: "Shirt",
              price: 1.9,
              count: 2
            },
            {
              index: 2,
              name: "Jeans",
              price: 1.9,
              count: 2
            }
          ]
        }
```

I have a react component showing cart products. Each product in the cart is a seperate div and having + and - buttons to increase, decrease the no of that product. On - click I want to decrease the quantity and also if count is reduced to 0 I want to remove this product as well from my redux state.
Now I have my reducer where first I am checking if the count is 1 then removing the product itself else reducing the count only. I am returning the state but its not updating the DOM

Can anyone help in this am I doing something wrong in returning state.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are directly manipulating the state, which will cause problems in React. Instead of `let chosenIds = state;`, you should copy the state, `let chosenIds = Object.assign({}, state);`. Then you can manipulate `chosenIds` as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to include a assignment statement in the else block.

```
  } else {
       chosenIds = [
          ...chosenIds.slice(0, index),
          { ...chosenIds[index], count: chosenIds[index].count - 1 },
          ...chosenIds.slice(index + 1)
        ];
      }
```

Instead of this complicated operation, you could use array.map to update a single item in the array.

```
 chosenIds = state.map(item => item.index === index ? {...item, count: item.count - 1} : item)
```